# How to print data by forloop with two different cards?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Here I have template for tags, and i want print them all by forloop but with the tag id.
e.g:

```
  {% for tag in tags %}
       <div class="row">
       
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <div class="photo-rounded-fluffs">
          <a href="#"> 
           <img class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'assets/img/fluffs/1.jpg'%}" alt="Image">
           <h1 class="text-center">{{tag.title}}</h1>#Here i want print tag with tag id 1
          </a> 
         </div>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <div class="photo-rounded-fluffs">
          <a href="#">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'assets/img/fluffs/2.jpg'%}" alt="Image">
           <h1 class="text-center">{{tag.title}}</h1> #here i want to print tag with id 2 
          </a> 
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
{% endfor%}
```

Right now the both tag title are same because same tag is repeating twice. How can I handle this behavior in forloop in templates.. If more information is required than tell me will update my question with that information.

Comment: You should have only one `div` within the for-loop, and use the properties from the `tag` variable. You would have a problem though with the correct image, I am afraid. I don't know enough about the templating language to help with this. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply add some conditions so if condition statisfy than that can print.

````
{% for tag in tags %}
     <div class="row">
      {% if tag.id ==1 %} 
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="photo-rounded-fluffs">
        <a href="#"> 
         <img class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'assets/img/fluffs/1.jpg'%}" alt="Image">
         <h1 class="text-center">{{tag.title}}</h1>#Here i want print tag with tag id 1
        </a> 
       </div>
      </div> 
              {% elif tag.id ==2%} 
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="photo-rounded-fluffs">
        <a href="#">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="{% static 'assets/img/fluffs/2.jpg'%}" alt="Image">
         <h1 class="text-center">{{tag.title}}</h1> #here i want to print tag with id 2 
        </a> 
       </div>
      </div>
      {% endif %} 
     </div>
{% endfor%}```
````